# Почему программа с UB у меня всегда работает правильно?

Tags: c++, c++11, неопределённое-поведение

тут же должно быть UB

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
int main()
{
    std::vector<char> s={'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o',  'w', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd'};
    auto beg=s.begin();
    while (beg!=s.end() && !isspace(*beg)) {
        *beg=toupper(*beg++);
    }
    for (auto i : s) std::cout << i << " ";
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: UB не означает верный крэш. UB означает, что что угодно имеет право случиться — включая и «нормальное» поведение программы.

Comment: А где вы видите UB?

Comment: В коде нет UB, а если бы было, смотрите комментарий @VladD.

Comment: Тут может (в зависимости от компилятора). Один будет при записи результата `toupper` брать адрес до увеличения `beg`, а другой после (и в этом случае вы увидите не `HELLO`, а  `hHHHH`) (впрочем, правильно ли называть это поведение UB или как-то еще, не знаю)

Comment: @ixSci, про равно — это так только в С++11 и выше (но тут как раз этот случай)

Comment: @Estet, выделите строчку, в которой по вашему мнению может быть неопределённое поведение

Comment: @ixSci, не буду спорить о С++ компиляторах. Но, если перевести код в компилируемый как Си, так и С++ (т.е. в `char *beg;`), то  `*beg = toupper(*beg++);` производит `hHHH...` в gcc version 5.4.0 (в т.ч. и с `-std=c11`) и `HELLO...` в g++ той же версии.

Comment: @avp, я не прав — может компилятор себе позволить то, что Вы описали (до C++17). Я сделал противоположное заявление совершив 2 ошибки. Первое, я мысленно переписал пример так: `beg.operator*().operator=(toupper(beg.operator++(0).operator*()));`, тогда как он должен быть переписан так: `beg.operator*() = toupper(beg.operator++(0).operator*());`. Сделав ошибку в переписывании, я совершил вторую ошибку: неправильно трактовал стандарт и решил, что `beg.` имеет приоритет и должен быть вычислен перед другими частями выражения — это не так (до C++17).

Comment: @mymedia, я ошибся, код в вопросе (`*beg=toupper(*beg++);`), будет давать unspecified результат вплоть до C++17. Объяснение ошибки есть в предыдущем комментарии.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Проблема кроется в строке, расположенной в цикле:

```
*beg=toupper(*beg++);
```

До c++17 это выражение может приводить к неопределённому поведению из-за отсутствия регламентированного порядка при вычислении левой и правой частей от оператора присваивания. Т.е. возможны следующие ситуации:

1. Сначала вычисляется левая часть. Мы запоминаем указатель на символ. Далее выполняем `toupper` и инкрементируем указатель. Пишем заглавную букву в запомненный ранее адрес. [В итоге получаем](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ZprRkUDT9nC3e9I2), вероятно то, что задумывалось:

   ```
   H E L L O W O R L D
   ```
2. Сначала вычисляется правая часть. Т.е. выполняется `toupper` для текущей буквы, указатель инкрементируется. Левая часть вычисляется уже на смещённом указателе и т.о. первый символ массива не изменяется вовсе и более того, мы пишем за концом вектора (явное UB). [На консоли увидим](https://wandbox.org/permlink/PJlDby69V7pDqqUV):

   ```
   h H H H H H H H H H
   ```

По ссылкам на результаты работы можно заметить, что использовались версии gcc 6.3 и 7.1 соответственно. Если глянуть в [список поддержки c++ фич gcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html#cxx1z), то можно увидеть в частности такой пункт:

> Refining Expression Evaluation Order for Idiomatic C++

со ссылкой на proposal [P0145R3](http://wg21.link/p0145), реализованный в версии 7. Основной момент здесь в том, что порядок вычисления выражений по разные стороны от `=` теперь регламентирован, сначала вычисляется правая часть, потом левая. Т.е. как раз наш случай #2 начиная с с++17 единственно возможный путь.

При сравнении пунктов стандарта C++11 и черновика под номером 4687 можно заметить, что в разделе `[expr.ass]` появилось предложение:

> The right operand is sequenced before the left operand.

Таким образом, представленный код содержит UB для c++17 и может содержать его в более старых стандартах, если реализации компиляторов будут выбирать описанную ветку #2. Но дело в том, что по стандарту до c++17 порядок этих вычислений не описан и даже чисто теоретически может быть разным на разных итерациях цикла. Поэтому гарантировать отсутствия UB в коде до c++17 нельзя.

Чтобы однозначно избежать проблем - достаточно обеспечить выполнение инкремента после увеличения регистра символа:

```
*beg=toupper(*beg);
beg++;
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64135/discussion-on-answer-by-alexolut----ub-----).